# Why isn't Vert.x being more used?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vert.x

[It is not a dev related question]

I have been using Vert.x since 2017 and I think the framework is great. It has a better performance when compared to Spring Boot, more requests per second and less cpu usage.

It works great for event driven programming and concurrent applications.

However, I don't see the community increasing. Does anyone know what are the cons keeping developers away from Vert.x? I'm about to start a new application and I feel worried about Vert.x is dying.

Comment: This is undoubtedly an interesting question, but it is primarily opinion-based, which makes it a poor fit for Stack Overflow. I am not sure it would be on-topic anywhere on the SE network, unfortunately.

Comment: @halfer Why should the first programming-oriented forum have to only offer snippets of code to copy/paste without thinking and without providing more rich debate about what we're doing? I think that kind of answer are counterproductive.

Comment: @Idriss: it has been firmly established over many years that debate does not work well in the Q&A format here - indeed that would be even more off-topic than this one. However, you can always [raise it on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if you wish.

Comment: @halfer Thanks, I think I'll take time to raise a debate on meta. Anyway I think it's really a shame to block that kind of questions and I wonder to know if I'm the only one to think like that.

Comment: @Idriss, no problem. Note that this discussion has been had a lot before, so do please do a thorough search on Meta, and see if you have new ideas to add. You aren't the only one to say this, but still in the minority, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I work for Red Hat in the Vert.x core team.

Thanks for sharing your good experience with Vert.x.

There is no secret sauce behind community growth: you need marketing money and a dedicated evangelist team. Vert.x has neither of these BUT:

- rest assured the project is not dead (we're releasing 4.0 in the coming months and Vert.x has become the network engine for Quarkus)
- the community is still very strong and vibrant (users helping each other on the forum and significant features are actually contributions)
- for a few years now Red Hat has offered commercial support

Rome wasn't built in a day: I first heard about Spring a few months after starting my career in IT 15 years ago...

Answer (score 3):

I think that over the past 20 years (maybe more), the technologies that have been the most used are those where the developer is able to stop thinking by himself and can produce a large amount of features as quickly as possible.

In other words, it's mainly the frameworks that handle everything for you: JSF, Struts that hide the frontend complexity for the backend devs that were not qualified, Spring who takes care of hiding all the problems of exposition and resiliency behind a mountain of annotations and abstraction layers. We could observe the same thing in the PHP world with Zend, Symfony, Laravel and whatever. And lately we can say the same thing for the frontend devs with Angular.

Using a toolkit like vert.x, in my opinion and even if we find it simple, requires a better understanding of what we're doing. We need to be aware of the reactor pattern, the asynchronous paradigm, the reactive programing, monothread and concurrent programing, etc. We need to stop designing standard blocking restful api to solve all the issues. We need to have a better control of communication issues and failover through our microservices. Even if toolkits like akka, vert.x, quarkus, micronaut had made lots of effort to give good documentations, industrialization tools, more libs around that handle many things for you... there still is an entrance ticket that management sometimes considers (wrongly in my mind) as an obstacle to the production.

Finally, I think that when a toolkit seems to answer exactly to your need and when there is a strong community behind (that doesn't have to be the biggest but that is made up of available experts and great oss companies like RedHat), you shouldn't wait to give it a try. It's often a better answer than big frameworks that handle too much things in the same box.